# Is there a cost of assigning an object variable?

Tags: c#, memory-management, compilation

Given a non-static class Foo with method DoSomething, the following two code snippets are valid:

```
Foo myFoo = new Foo();
Foo.DoSomething();
```

or

```
new Foo().DoSomething();
```

Given the situation where I don't need to do anything else with Foo, and can happily throw it away after the call to DoSomething, is there a preference between these two, or do they compile to the same thing?

I know that there's probably a better way of writing Foo, but I'm not in a position to do that at the moment, so I'm just wondering about the best way to use what I've got.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the IL:

Case 1.

```
var t = new Foo();
t.DoSomething();
```

compiles to

```
IL_0000:  newobj     instance void Tests.Foo::.ctor()
IL_0005:  stloc.0
IL_0006:  ldloc.0
IL_0007:  callvirt   instance void Tests.Foo::DoSomething()
IL_000c:  ret
```

Case 2.

```
new Foo().DoSomething();
```

compiles to

```
IL_0000:  newobj     instance void Tests.Foo::.ctor()
IL_0005:  call       instance void Tests.Foo::DoSomething()
IL_000a:  ret
```

The latter is two instructions shorter than the first, but you shouldn't worry about this unless you have a huge number of calls to this because it will be an insignificant difference.

Comment: I think you mean "insignificant difference" :-). But excellent answer.

Comment: @user1158174 right, I was thinking about something else